# Is there any `affected_rows` equivalent for SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category` = ?
```

Is there anyway to know, using `mysqli` and without fetching, if this statement returned an empty result?

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category` = ?");
$sql->bind_param('s', $category);
$sql->execute();

var_dump($sql);
exit();
```

As you can see, I'm using var_dump to see if there is any property I can use for this purpose. Here's the result:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { 
["affected_rows"]=> int(-1)
["insert_id"]=> int(0)
["num_rows"]=> int(0)
["param_count"]=> int(1)
["field_count"]=> int(7)
["errno"]=> int(0) 
["error"]=> string(0) "" 
["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000"
["id"]=> int(2) }
```

I see nothing that can serve the purpose of knowing if the query returned some lines or not.

---

Alternatively, is it possible to solve this entire problem in the query itself? For example, will `if (SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = ?, RETURN 1, RETURN 0)` always return 1 if the query successfully returns some lines?

I'd like to delete a category from a database only if no products are associated with it: doing so in just a few lines of code would be much better, but I'm not totally sure if this will work

```
if (SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = ?, RETURN 1, (DELETE FROM categories WHERE name = ?))
```

Which is the best way to do this? Thanks.

---

edit: num_rows isn't working

```
$sql->bind_param('s', $c);
$sql->execute();

while($sql->fetch())
printf("one line - " . "\n");

var_dump($sql->num_rows);
exit();
```

result:

> one line - one line - one line - one line - one line - one line -
>   int(0)

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE ...` ?

Comment: won't that count the number of columns? I'd like to count the number of returned lines.

Comment: oh! It is returning the number of lines - never used COUNT before and wasn't expecting it to work this way. Thanks!

Comment: it's number of rows not number of lines, number of lines is so confusing... if <p> is there number of line may increase, use number of rows or records

Comment: `affected_rows` is used for update query not for select query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to achieve this. In your case I'd do something like this:

```
$result = $sql->query();
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
```

instead of `$sql->execute();`.

Comment: @Saturnix, you didn't change the line `$sql->execute()` to use `query()` and you're not grabbing the `$result` either. The `num_rows` is on the result object, not the `$sql` object.

Comment: I must use `execute()` since I'm using a prepared statement.

Comment: Solved by googling "prepared statement num_rows". Found this: http://foundationphp.com/blog/2011/09/24/using-num_rows-with-a-mysqli-prepared-statement/ You should update your answer by addressing the need of using a prepared statement. Accepted anyway, but consider updating if you're willing to :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution via sql query:

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM `table_name` GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT( * ) > 0)
```